# Persistent Database Unresponsiveness Issue in NestJS Production Environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm encountering problems with my NestJS (TypeOrm) application. In the production environment, after a certain period, the database becomes unresponsive. This issue persists until I restart the server. Following the server restart, the database functions normally again for a while. The same problem recurs periodically.

Comment: sounds like you are not managing your connections properly and over time they pile up without ever being closed

Comment: @GoranLegenda thanks, but i thought TypeOrm Handles connection closing automatically